# Dynamically changing the json from Rest Servic

Tags: c#, json, rest

I have the json format as follows.. I need to add a child "tabledata" to "template variables" using c# . Any help would be appreciated.

```
 "templatevariables": [
              {

                "Stationery List Details": [
                  {
                    "Stationery Item": "HIGHLIGHTER PEN",
                    "Quantity": "2"
                  },]}]
```

New Structure should look like.

```
"templatevariables": [
                  {
                    "tabledata": [
                      {
                        "Stationery List Details": [
                          {
                            "Stationery Item": "BLACK BOARD DUSTER",
                            "Quantity": "5"
                          }
                        ]}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your question is very vague, and if you don't have any problem creating the first result, you shouldn't have any problem with the second one as well, but as maybe you're missing something, I post the answer which maybe help you:

```
    public dynamic Get()//your action
    {

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            templatevariables =
            new
            {
                tabledata = new
                {
                    Stationery_List_Details = new
                    {
                        Stationery_Item = "BLACK BOARD DUSTER",
                        Quantity = 5
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: No.. Actually, On hitting a URL i am getting the above json format.. which I wuld like to dynamically change with my c# code

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this type of behavior? What are your clients suppose to do with this ? How would they consume different responses?

anyways, you could always: 
create two objects and return them as per your conditions. 
You can use inheritance to minimize code duplicatcy .